# Can you post to a Facebook group with a Facebook page which is not admin of that Facebook group?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups

So now you can post to a Facebook group with a Facebook page which has been set as administrator of that Facebook group. But can you do the same with a Facebook page which is *not* administrator of that Facebook group?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you can't post a Facebook group with a Facebook page which isn't admin of that Facebook group.

Comment: [A year later it became possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121789/why-can-only-some-of-my-facebook-pages-interact-with-groups).