# Can you post to a Facebook group, as a Facebook page set as admin of that group, from the mobile version of Facebook?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups

So far I can post to a Facebook group, as a Facebook page set as admin of that group, but from the web version of Facebook. I want to do the same but from the mobile version of Facebook. When I try to switch to page in the option "publish as" (page or user) it selects me back the option user.

Can this be done?

Comment: Please do not post [cross question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110050/87130).

Comment: @serenesat they are 2 different questions, with 2 possible different solutions. Completely unrelated. I would clarify them more if possible, but they are written as specific as they can be. 2 different user cases, if you want to put it in coding terms.