# Why can only some of my Facebook Pages interact with Groups?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups

Facebook has recently added the ability for pages to join groups.
When I enter a group as myself, I'm presented with the choice join the group as one of my pages. However, the choice is just for a few of my pages and not for all of them. Why is that?

[image: Why not all pages?]

Comment: How is it showing for those pages which do not have option to join group? Can you show that?

Comment: Those pages aren't showing at all. When I click this option I see only X pages out of Y. It's not like the other page are grayed out, but simply not showing up at all.

Comment: And your role to those pages are _Admin_?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I am also  having the same issue. I admin multiple pages, but when I try to interact/join a group, it only lists 1 of them, and not the one I want to use.

Comment: How many groups is your page already connected to? I'm wondering if i've reached some limit on my page. I think I have 69 or 70 groups, and 2 which I admin.

Comment: No, it also happens with pages that are presently connected to no groups. It's either they can be connected or not at all.

Comment: I have attempted a few things (found on other sites) that have yet to yield results. Went to https://business.facebook.com/settings and added my page to my name there (I was already admin, so it approved automatically). I noticed my page that can join groups has the fan badges options, so I followed settings to get that in hopes they were also preventing me from joining groups. Sites said to switch to the video template option in the page settings. Nothing has worked yet, waiting to see if updates take some time to change everywhere.

Comment: My page that is missing is also an older page, so it is not the case of being a new page as some sites describe.

Comment: I also have this issue, I have 5 pages, and 4 of them can join the groupx. Strange thing is, all 5 pages can join groupy, groupz... but, for some reason, groupx and page5 seem not to go together.

Comment: Please edit the question to add all the relevant details to the question body. Note: The following discussion has been featured: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/). I'm proposing that on most questions on Web Apps SE should be required to show the help center has been reviewed. In this case, the screenshot shows  a "Learn more" link. What do the linked articles say about this issue? Does it include links to related issues or common questions? Does this feature and issue still exists in 2023?

Comment: I found this question on top of the unanswered questions.

Comment: Good call, [a new answer posted](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172016/104287).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it took a few years to fix it, but it was fixed nonetheless. It seems pages of certain type can no longer be blocked.

The new flow is much more confusing though:

1. Enter the Group and see the Join button.
2. **Manually** switch to a Page.
3. If the Join button is clickable you can join the group.

The confusing part is there's no indication a Page can join too. You have to manually switch to the Page to even try. So far I encountered Groups that block Pages in general, but no longer only certain types of Pages.

Answer (score -2):

Groups may designate whether they allow "Pages" to join, or only "Members". The difference being that if you are applying to join as yourself, or as a fan page/business page/etc.

If the group does not allow Pages to become members then this option will not even show up.

According to Facebook this is due to Pages abusing their group memberships by spamming the groups members.

Comment: While true, this doesn't fully answer the question -- there is (at least) one group that I can join with one of my pages, not with the other. Both pages are years old with good reputation.

Comment: Yeah, while true, it is not the answer to the question. The questions is not "why i can't join X group with my page" the question is "why some of my pages are eligible from joining groups, but others don't even appear on the eligible list when joining a group that already allows pages as members".