# Why is one of my Facebook pages not able to join groups but all of the other ones are?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

When I go to join a group on Facebook it gives the option of which profile or page I want to join as. I can either select my personal profile or 3 out of 4 of my pages. The 1 page I want to join the group as doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Welcome. Please also have a look at [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121789/why-can-only-some-of-my-facebook-pages-interact-with-groups).